# Convert '2019-10-16' do date object

Tags: python

I realize this might be the most well-documented thing on the Internet but I can't seem to get it right. I have a string, '2019-10-16' that I want to turn into a date object so I can increase it incrementally, but can still be converted to the string '2019-10-06' again. However, I seem to only be able to get it as 2019.10.16 or something similar.

```
import datetime
day = '2019-10-16'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(day, '%Y-%m-%d')
>date_object
>datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 16, 0, 0)
```

Comment: have you checked `datetime.datetime.strftime()` ?

Comment: `date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Edit: that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change it use `date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`